# JavaScript - Detecting Key Presses

Tags: javascript, keypress, addeventlistener

I am using addEventListener to check the user's keypresses,
but there are some problems.

This is my code:

```
// get key presses

var keys = {
  up: false,
  down: false,
  left: false,
  right: false
}

function keyUpdate(keyEvent, down) {
  // down is a boolean, whether the key event is keydown (true) or keyup (false)
  switch (keyEvent.keyCode) {

    case 38:
      keys.up = down;
      break;

    case 40:
      keys.down = down;
      break;

    case 37:
      keys.left = down;
      break;

    case 39:
      keys.right = down;
      break;
  }
}

document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
  keyUpdate(event, true);
});

document.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  keyUpdate(event, false);
});
```

This code has two problems:

- It doesn't seem to let more than 2 keys be active at once
- It seems to constantly update the `keys` variables when it should only be
  updating it when a key is first pressed or released. This might be a
  performance issue, but it's not that important.

Why do I have these problems?

EDIT: Looking at the answers, I have come to the conclusion that it is a problem with my browser/computer. It seems to only happen with the arrow keys. As mobius said, it is really not necessary for more than two keys to be active at once.

Comment: Use the `keypress` event instead

Comment: @adeneo `onkeypress` does not fire for arrow keys on Chrome, IE, or Safari.

Comment: document.addEventListener("input", function(event) {

Comment: That is correct, so I guess you're stuck with `keydown`/`keyup` then, and they all have issues like this, constantly firing, and no multiple keys etc.

Comment: I'm not experiencing none of the issues you noted in the question.

Comment: So, what? Edit the question and give more details

Comment: What specifically are you trying to do that you can't do? Do you really need to press more than two arrows at the same time? does that even make sense? In my example, you can use the WASD keys to get at least 3 at once on my setup. Does this work for you? If it does please accept some answer, if not, please clarify your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to get at two keys to show at once with the code you provided. I have modified the example to display the data, and a graphical representation. If you are not seeing multiple keys work at once, it is probably a browser limitation.

I am using Chrome 53 on OSX

```js
// get key presses

var keys = {
  up: false,
  down: false,
  left: false,
  right: false
}

function keyUpdate(keyEvent, down) {
  // down is a boolean, whether the key event is keydown (true) or keyup (false)
  keyEvent.preventDefault(); // prevent screen from going crazy while i press keys.
  console.log(keyEvent.keyCode)
  switch (keyEvent.keyCode) {

    case 87: // W key.
    case 38:  // up key.
      keys.up = down;
      var key = document.querySelector('.up');
      if (down){
        key.classList.add('pressed');
      } else {
        key.classList.remove('pressed');
      }
      break;
      
    case 83: // S key
    case 40: // down key
      keys.down = down;
      var key = document.querySelector('.down');
      if (down){
        key.classList.add('pressed');
      } else {
        key.classList.remove('pressed');
      }
      break;

    case 65: // A key
    case 37: // left arrow.
      keys.left = down;
      var key = document.querySelector('.left');
      if (down){
        key.classList.add('pressed');
      } else {
        key.classList.remove('pressed');
      }
      break;
    case 68:
    case 39: // right arrow.
      keys.right = down;
      var key = document.querySelector('.right');
      if (down){
        key.classList.add('pressed');
      } else {
        key.classList.remove('pressed');
      }
      break;
    default:
      if (down){
         keys[keyEvent.keyCode] = down;
      } else if (keyEvent.keyCode in keys){
        delete keys[keyEvent.keyCode];
      }
  }
  var text = JSON.stringify(keys, null, 4);
  document.querySelector('.code').innerHTML = text;
}

document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
  keyUpdate(event, true);
});

document.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  keyUpdate(event, false);
});


document.querySelector('.code').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(keys, null, 4);
```

```css
h3 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-weight: normal;
}
.keys {
  width: 150px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.rows {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items : center;
}

.key{
  flex: 1;
  width: 50px;
  max-width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #eee;
  text-align:center;
  line-height: 50px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  transition: all .2s ease;
  color : #555;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.pressed{
  color : #ddd;
  background-color: #aaa;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
}

.columns{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-arround;
}

.code {
  background-color: #efefef;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
}
```

```html
<h3> click here to start capturing keyboard input</h1>
<div class="keys rows">
  <div class="key up">↑</div>
  <div class="columns">
    <div class="key left">←</div>
        <div class="key down">↓</div>
    <div class="key right">→</div>
  </div>
</div>
<pre class="code">
</pre>
```

**EDIT**: on further inspection the restriction to only two keys at once seems to be limited to arrow keys. I have updated the example to show any currently pressed keys by key code in addition to arrow keys. You will notice that you can add more than two.

**edit 2** I use the dvorak keyboard layout, and didn't realize that I had set the WASD keys wrong. They are now correct for standard QWERTY layouts.

Comment: To clarify: I have been able to get 2 keys, but not more. I am still unable to get more than two keys with your snippet, so it's probably a problem with Chrome. That's too bad...

Comment: I was only able to get 2 in firefox as well, so i'm beginning to think it is an operating system issue. What is your os?

Comment: The limitation does not seem to be two keys, but rather a limit of the number of keys on a certain row or column. I have updated the example to show all currently pressed keys, and to use WASD in addition to Arrow keys.

Comment: whoever left the downvote, could you please comment as to why?

Comment: @Challenger5, I have updated the code to show non/arrow functions, and it seems i am able to get more that two keys, but no more than a certain number of keys in some groupings. I am starting to suspect columns or rows or something like that

Answer (score 1):

Use keypress event, so that it is only executed when the user presses a key and not while they are pressing it.

```
document.addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {
    keyUpdate(event, true);
});

document.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
    keyUpdate(event, false);
});
```

Comment: `keypress` does not work with arrow keys on IE, Safari, or Chrome.

Comment: Yes it does. I developed a small game with JavaScript and I used that event and works fine for me. I use Chrome.